# Retrieving comments and reply with limits

Tags: mysql, post, join, comments, limit

I still do not find the right way to do it the way i want it. What I try to achieve is a comment post section that will show the 2 last reply of the post

my tables structure are like this

```
table post
---------------------
post_id | comment | post_user | post_date

post_reply
---------------------
reply_id | parent_id | reply_user | reply_date
```

actually i am able to fetch all the post and all the reply but the problem that i face is i want to limit the number of post that i fetch and the number of reply for each post that i fetch and i also want to display the post if there is no reply then result should look like this

```
result
----------------------------------------------
post 1
reply post 1
reply post 1
post 2 
post 3
reply post 3 
reply post 3
```

of course I want to display this till I reach 10 post and the 2 reply max attach to each post with the less query possible of course. actually i am using a while that query for each post the 2 last reply but that use 11 query every time maybe you guys know a better way to do it in less query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your ID columns are of type INT. If not, you might have to use variables to count the replies per post, described [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/).

So try this

```
SELECT 'POST' AS type, p1.post_id, p1.comment, p1.post_user, p1.post_date, '-' AS reply_id
 FROM post p1
 LIMIT 10

UNION

SELECT 'REPLY' AS type, pr.parent_id AS post_id, 
 '-' AS comment, pr.reply_user AS post_user, pr.reply_date AS post_date, pr.reply_id
 FROM post_reply pr
 JOIN (
     SELECT p2.post_id 
     FROM post p2 
     LIMIT 10
 ) AS tmpPost ON pr.parent_id = tmpPost.post_id
 JOIN (
     SELECT pr.reply_id, COUNT(*) AS row_number
     FROM post_reply pr 
     JOIN post_reply pr2 ON pr.parent_id = pr2.parent_id AND pr.reply_id >= pr2.reply_id
     GROUP BY pr.reply_id
 ) AS tmpPostRN ON tmpPostRN.reply_id = pr.reply_id
 WHERE tmpPostRN.row_number <= 2

ORDER BY post_id ASC, type ASC, reply_id ASC
```

The Result will be something like

```
+-------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+
| type  | post_id | comment   | post_user       | post_date  | reply_id |
+-------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+
| POST  |       1 | comment1  | user1           | 0000-00-00 | -1       |
| REPLY |       1 | -         | post 1 reply1   | 0000-00-00 | 1        |
| REPLY |       1 | -         | post 1 reply 2  | 0000-00-00 | 2        |
| POST  |       2 | comment2  | user2           | 0000-00-00 | -1       |
| POST  |       3 | comment3  | user3           | 0000-00-00 | -1       |
| REPLY |       3 | -         | post 3 reply 1  | 0000-00-00 | 3        |
| REPLY |       3 | -         | post 3 reply 2  | 0000-00-00 | 4        |
| POST  |       4 | comment4  | user 4          | 0000-00-00 | -1       |
| POST  |       5 | comment5  | user 5          | 0000-00-00 | -1       |
| POST  |       6 | comment6  | user6           | 0000-00-00 | -1       |
| POST  |       7 | comment7  | user7           | 0000-00-00 | -1       |
| POST  |       8 | comment8  | user8           | 0000-00-00 | -1       |
| POST  |       9 | comment9  | user9           | 0000-00-00 | -1       |
| POST  |      10 | comment10 | user10          | 0000-00-00 | -1       |
| REPLY |      10 | -         | post 10 reply 1 | 0000-00-00 | 5        |
| REPLY |      10 | -         | post 10 reply 2 | 0000-00-00 | 6        |
+-------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+
```

Instead of `'-' AS comment` in the second query you can insert your comment column in your post_reply table (provided that you have one). You can also set your reply_id for posts to a default value of your choice (rather than -1).

Comment: thank you very much to have reply to this post i will test this right away when ill be back home.

Comment: that work pretty well the only issue i see is that return me 2 reply what is pretty good but that return the 2 first reply can it be for the 2 last reply from post_reply ?

Comment: just replace `pr.reply_id >= pr2.reply_id` in the subquery with `pr.reply_id <= pr2.reply_id`